# Removing commas from javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have 3 strings "a","b","c" in javascript array "testarray".

```
var testarray=new Array("a","b","c");
```

and then I am printing the value of testarray using javascript alert box.

```
alert(testarray);
```

The result will be like  a,b,c

All these strings are separated by "," character. I want to replace this "," with some other character or combination of two or more characters so that the alert box will show something like `a%b%c` or `a%$b%$c`

Comment: I am being over picky here but declare arrays using `var testarray= ["a","b","c"]` rather than `var testarray=new Array("a","b","c");`it reads easier an avoids a few potential issues.

Comment: thanks for the tip. will figure it out next time :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the [`join` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
alert(testarray.join("%")); // 'a%b%c'
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MjELW/). Note that by passing the empty string to `join` you can get the concatenation of all elements of the array:

```
alert(testarray.join("")); // 'abc'
```

---

*Side note*: it's generally considered better practice to use an array literal instead of the `Array` constructor when creating an array:

```
var testarray = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Answer (score 8):

you can iterate through the array and insert your characters

```
var testarray=new Array("a","b","c");
var str;
for (var i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++) {
  str+=testarray[i]+"%";
}
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

use testarray is getting converted in string using `testarray.toString()` before alert. toString internally joining these items using ',' as separator. you can convert it into string using `Array.join` and pass own separator.

`alert(testarray.join("%"));`